# PDF cannot be read

Tags: pdf

I programmatically created a PDF with object streams and encryption, but while several PDF viewers can read it, some fail.

PDF readers, which can read it:

- Foxit
- Google Chrome
- Nuance
- Nitro
- pdf.js

PDF readers, which cannot read it:

- Adobe Reader
- PDF X/Change

Currently i am blind to see, what the problem inside the PDF is. Can anyone help? The PDF can be downloaded at https://www.doxisafe.me/#!/retrieve/ivqkli

The PDF is encrypted with an owner password "owner" and no user password.

Comment: Can you create one without object streams or encryption to see if it will work..

Comment: A PDF created without object streams and using encryption and xref stream worked. A PDF created with object streams, but without encryption worked. Just the combination seems not to work.

Comment: May be you should ask on this forum https://forums.adobe.com/community/adobe_reader_forums/content?filterID=contentstatus%5Bpublished%5D~objecttype~objecttype%5Bthread%5D

Comment: RUPS reports problems reading the XML metadata stream (but shows the metadata nonetheless). I'd start searching there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today i found a solution, that Adobe just requires the Catalog dictionary not to be in an object stream, when the file is encrypted. This is not following the pdf spec, which claims, that only the following objects shouldn't be inside the object stream:

- Stream objects
- Objects with a generation number other than zero
- A document’s encryption dictionary (see 7.6, "Encryption")
- An object representing the value of the Length entry in an object stream dictionary
- In linearized files (see Annex F), the document catalog, the linearization dictionary, and page objects shall not appear in an object stream.

My file is not linearized, so the last condition shall not apply.

Comment: [PDF 32000 7.5.7 Object Streams] also states "The offsets in the object-stream shall be in increasing". Looks like they aren't in the linked PDF, which might cause a problem.

Comment: In the linked PDF the object stream header looks like this:
1.0.4.86.5.121.7.382.8.493.10.15414.11.15466
so the object with number 1 is at offset 0, the object with 4 at offset 86,.... They are all in increasing order.

Comment: Your analysis is duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56522926/1729265) in the comments. You probably should accept your answer (click the tick at its upper left) to make it a better find.