# Why is an encrypted PDF with object streams invalid for Acrobat Reader but opens fine in any other viewer

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to figure out why a PDF created/modified by [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) (note: I'm the author of this library/application) is not valid according to Adobe Acrobat Reader. It opens fine in any other PDF viewer I have tried.

I was able to narrow down the problem to having something to do with object streams in an encrypted PDF file. When not using object streams, the encrypted file works fine.

Comparing the file created by HexaPDF with files created by other tools didn't lead to any real insight yet. And the internal structure of the PDF also seems fine.

A sample PDF that fails in Acrobat Reader is available [here](https://github.com/gettalong/hexapdf/files/3268627/outn-bad.pdf) - Edit: password is 'test'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any chance of sharing the password ? Its hard to decrypt without it....

Comment: Yes, sorry, its 'test' - I have updated the question. Acrobat Reader doesn't even ask for the password

Comment: At a quick glance I can't see any problems, I'm travelling at the moment I'll look more thoroughly tomorrow. Its an intriguing problem !

Comment: Thanks - very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so this is interesting. Its impossible to be absolutely certain, because (obviously) I don't have access to the Acrobat source, but it looks to me like you have found an unsupported combination in Acrobat.

If you try to create a similar file from Adobe Acrobat, by applying security to an existing PDF file, you don't get a fully flexible interface. This is probably reasonable, since the average user would simply be baffled by the potential choices.

Instead you get to choose 'Compatibility', which is a version of Acrobat to be compatible with. Now your file uses security handler version 2, whcih was introduced in PDF 1.4, but its a PDF 1.5 file, and it uses xref streams, which are a PDF 1.5 feature.

I tried creating files with compatibility set to Acrobat 5 (PDF 1.4) and Acrobat 6 (PDF 1.5). The Acrobat 5 file uses security handler /V 2 but no xref streams, and the Acrobat 6 file has xref streams **but** it uses security handler /V 4.

I can see nothing whatever wrong with your file, and as you say all the PDF consumers I've tried are happy with it. So I don't believe its a problem with your file creation, it seems likely to me that Acrobat simply doesn't support PDF 1.5 with Security handler /V 2, it insists that you use /V 4.

Reading your question it sounds like you've already tried using /V 2 without a compressed xref (or object streams) and its OK. The other thing you might try is changing from security handler /V 2 to /V 4 and see if that works, my bet is that it will.

I guess you would want to be compatible with Acrobat, so I imagine you'll want to ensure you don't create this combination, if someone insists, you perhaps might want to warn them that its not compatible with Acrobat.

Comment: Thanks for investigating further! I have tried using /V 4 and it still doesn't work... When using /V 2 or /V 4 with object streams, Acrobat complains. However, when just using xref streams *without* object streams, it works fine. See https://gist.github.com/gettalong/7602fe9e9b0b71fd094e9f6b815fafbd for all test files.

Comment: One more thing: It really seems that HexaPDF does something "wrong" when using object streams in conjunction with encryption. The sample file encrypted with qpdf  (also in the latest version of the gist) works fine in Acrobat (PDF 1.5, /V 2, xref and object streams).

Comment: Intriguing, let me look further. Its curious that other PDF consumers can read the file regardless.

Comment: Well MuPDF complains about object 7 in bad1.pdf having an incorrect header check (zlib error). Which makes me think that either the stream isn't encrypted or the encryption is incorrect, since its Flate encoded as well its a little harder to check :-)

Comment: Hmm... that's weird... If I move object 1 (Catalog dictionary) out of the object stream 7, there is no more zlib error with mutool... And it works in Acrobat! I have updated the gist with good3.pdf to reflect this. Side note: Even though mutool throws this error, it can still decode the stream correctly. And if I remove the Flate encoding mutool still throws the zlib error and can still decode the stream.

Comment: Sorry, that was too quick: mutool *doesn't* throw the zlib error anymore but still throws the other errors...

Comment: My slightly old version (1.14) of mutool isn't throwing any problems with your modified file at all. It does look like you've put your finger on it with the Catalog not being in a compressed object stream. I have to say that's weird, the spec says it has to be an indirect object, but I can't see anything saying it must not be in a compressed object stream.....Hmm, I do see (p1025 of the 1.7 reference) that **linearized** files must not have the catalog (amongst other things) compressed. Still looks like an Acrobat bug to me :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that insight :-) I haven't come around to implementing linearization so haven't read that part of the spec in depth. I agree with you and blame Acrobat ;-) Thanks for your help in figuring this out!

Comment: This final analysis effectively duplicates [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300803/1729265).

Comment: Thanks @mkl - I have updated the question title to make it better findable.